# ZSH find with multiple operators

Tags: zsh

If I want to search for a directory or symlinks, I can do the following in **bash**:

```
find . \( -type d -o -type l \) -maxdepth 1
```

The same command doesn't work in **ZSH**:

```
find: missing argument to `-type'
): No such file or directory
-maxdepth: No such file or directory
1: No such file or directory
```

So I guess some more escaping or similar is needed. Is there a way to specify this command so that it works in both - ZSH and bash?

Here the output of `setopt` in ZSH:

```
alwaystoend
autocd
autopushd
nobeep
nocheckjobs
completeinword
extendedhistory
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histfindnodups
histignorealldups
histignoredups
histignorespace
histsavenodups
histverify
nohup
incappendhistory
interactive
interactivecomments
longlistjobs
monitor
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
pushdminus
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
```

My ZSH version is: zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

Of course, I'm using Oh My Zsh.

Comment: Have you tried single quotes around the parentheses instead of the backslashes?  Double quotes?  I'd be surprised if those give `zsh` conniptions, but I don't use `zsh` (yet, with no plans to move soon, though Apple may end up forcing my hand; Bash is still `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)` on macOS).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in zsh 5.4.2. This is only a guess, but maybe some of your zsh options cause this behavior. If so, please add the output of `setopt`.

Comment: @Socowi Added output of setopt.

Comment: also no error on zsh+omz 5.8 on linux and macos. linux did complain about the last arg being "-maxdepth N", suggesting it should come first.

Comment: Long shot: is there a global alias defined for `l`?

Comment: @chepner Exactly, that's the problem! Just found it myself by commenting out all options and aliases defined in my .zshrc.

Comment: @chepner : How come, that an gets expanded in the middle of a statement? I thought they are only obeyed in the _command_ position.

Comment: @user1934428 I had a global alias `l` defined, which also gets expanded in the middle of a command :-(

Comment: @Sebi : Creepy! I never used this feature... There are still plenty of things to explore on the dark side of zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP confirmed that a global alias for `l` was defined, which altered the set of arguments seen by `find`, leading to the error.